# How to join 3 tables in postgresql query using postgresql join

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have 3 different tables. The name of these tables is ro_master,tank_master,du_master.

Below is tables data:

ro_master:

```
id |  cms_code  |    ro_name    |      ro_address      
----+------------+---------------+----------------------    
  9 | 55381XA386 | RGE Name      | 89, Nilkamal Society    
  7 | 55381XA384 | Demo Name1    | 89, Nilkamal Society    
  5 | 55381XA381 | ABC Petroluem | Demo Address    
  6 | 55381XA383 | ABC Petroluem | Demo Address    
  8 | 55381XA385 | DEF Name      | 89, Nilkamal Society    
  4 | 55381XA382 | Demo Name     | Demo Address
```

tank_master:

```
id | product | cms_code_id 
----+---------+-------------
 12 | HSD     |           4    
 13 | HSD     |           4    
 11 | MS      |           4    
 15 | HSD     |           7    
 16 | HSD     |           7    
 17 | MS      |           7    
 14 | MS      |           7    
 18 | XP      |           4    
 19 | HSD     |           4    
 20 | MS      |           9    
 21 | HSD     |           9
```

du_master:

```
id | du_make | du_type | cms_code_id 
----+---------+---------+-------------
  6 | Midco   | Dual    |           7    
  7 | GVR     | MPD     |           7    
  8 | GVR     | MPD     |           7    
  9 | GVR     | MPD     |           7    
 10 | Midco   | Dual    |           4    
 11 | GVR     | MPD     |           4    
 12 | GVR     | QPD     |           4    
 13 | Midco   | Dual    |           4    
 14 | Midco   | QPD     |           7    
 15 | Midco   | QPD     |           7    
 16 | Midco   | Dual    |           9    
 17 | Midco   | MPD     |           9    
 18 | Midco   | Dual    |           9
```

Now i want join all three table. using specific ro_master ids(ex. id: 4,7).

I used below query:

```
SELECT rm.cms_code,rm.ro_name,rm.ro_address,
    tm.product,dm.du_type
FROM ro_master rm left JOIN
     tank_master tm
     ON rm.id = tm.cms_code_id left join du_master dm
     ON rm.id = dm.cms_code_id
WHERE rm.id in (4,7);
```

The result i got:

```
cms_code  |  ro_name   |      ro_address      | product | du_type 
------------+------------+----------------------+---------+---------    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | Dual    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | QPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | QPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | Dual    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | QPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | MS      | QPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | Dual    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | QPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | QPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | Dual    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | MPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | QPD    
 55381XA384 | Demo Name1 | 89, Nilkamal Society | HSD     | QPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | Dual    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | MPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | QPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | Dual    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | XP      | Dual    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | XP      | MPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | XP      | QPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | XP      | Dual    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | MS      | Dual    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | MS      | MPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | MS      | QPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | MS      | Dual    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | Dual    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | MPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | QPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | Dual    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | Dual    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | MPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | QPD    
 55381XA382 | Demo Name  | Demo Address         | HSD     | Dual
```

result i need like this:
[image: 1]

Comment: I only see a formatting problem (not repeating values that are the same on the previous row). than problem should not be solved in postgresql,

Comment: Why not just concatenate the last three columns into arrays?

Comment: For id=7 you have 4 rows in one joined table and 6 rows in the other.  How you want only 5 rows  in the result? please explain.

Comment: @Serg yes it's 6 rows by mistake i only add 5 rows

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tank_master` and `du_master` must be joined positionally when sorted by `id`

```
SELECT rm.cms_code,rm.ro_name,rm.ro_address,
    tdm.product, tdm.du_type
FROM ro_master rm 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT coalesce(dm.cms_code_id, tm.cms_code_id) cms_code_id,
           tm.product, dm.du_type  
     FROM (
        select *,
           row_number() over(partition by cms_code_id order by id) rn 
        from tank_master) tm
     FULL JOIN(
        select *,
           row_number() over(partition by cms_code_id order by id) rn 
        from du_master) dm  
      ON dm.cms_code_id = tm.cms_code_id AND tm.rn = dm.rn
  ) tdm ON rm.id = tdm.cms_code_id 
WHERE rm.id in (4,7);
```